# Using push() to add values to indexes within an empty multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm not sure if my question makes sense, but in further detail, I don't understand how I would push a value into an empty Multidimensional array.

For Example

```
var x = 1;
var y = 2;

//tried this
var arr1 = [[,]];
for (var i  = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    arr1[i][0].push(x), arr1[i][1].push(y) 
}

//Basically I want [[1,2], etc... ]
```

I'm a starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function add() {
    // add values to multidimensional array
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
    var array = [];
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        array.push([x, y]);
    }
    console.log(array);
}
add();
```

result: [ [1,2], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2] ]

```
function replace() {
    // replace values in multidimensional array
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
    var array = [['',''],['','']];
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i][0] = x;
        array[i][1] = y;
    }
    console.log(array);
}
replace();
```

result: [ [1,2], [1,2] ]

you can check the console log and it'll show you the results

Answer (score 0):

You can add elements into a two dimensional array with the following code

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {  
  var arr2 = new Array();
  for(var key in arr1[i]) {
    arr2.push(arr1[i][key]);
  }
  arr1.push(arr2); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

```
// 1st option
var arr1 = []
for (var i  = 0; i < count; i++){
    arr1.push([x,y]);
}

// 2nd option
var arr1 = [[],[]]
for (var i  = 0; i < count; i++){
    arr1[i].push(x,y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You ask to use "push" to fill multi-dimensional array**

So let's say you want your array in this form:

```
arr1 = [ elem1, elem2, elem3, ..., elemN ]
```

Where each `elem#n` is an array so it is multidimensional array:

```
arr1 = [ [0, a], [1, b], [2, c], ... ]
```

Since "push" adds a new element to the array, you will need to "push" an "array element" to the array like this:

```
arr1 = [];
arr1.push([1,100]); // arr1 <---- [ [1,100] ]
arr1.push([2,101]); // arr1 <---- [ [1,100], [2,101] ]
arr1.push([3,102]); // arr1 <---- [ [1,100], [2,101], [3,102] ]
```

So in your case, you want to use loop to add array element where the first is 'index' and the second is 'value', you can do this:

```
var length = 5; 
var x = 5;
for (var u=0; u<length; u++){
    arr1.push( [u,x] );
}
// arr1 <-- [ [0,5], [1,5], [2,5], [3,5], [4,5] ]
```

Hope this clarifies your understanding about using "push" to make multi-dimensional array.